# Intercepting A Dock Icon Click in OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm looking for a way to intercept all dock icon clicks(so I can display various windows in my own way). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [NSDockTilePlugin dockMenu] and see if overriding that takes care of what you want to do.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSDockTilePlugIn_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDockTilePlugIn/dockMenu

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me.

Note that I just wanted to get notified of the dock icon clicked, I did not intend to customize the display of the window list - so it is solves a sligthly smaller problem than the OP had. But since search led me here, I think this answer will help others too.

Within applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
         name:NSApplicationWillBecomeActiveNotification
       object:nil];
```

Then I get notified here:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)application {
    // The dock icon was clicked, do your thing.
}
```